# Paginated form with ajax checkboxes throws "The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable"

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, paging

Using Drupal **8.7.7** I have a form which consists of a paginated table of users.

Each user row has a checkbox element in the form with an ajax event attached.  This is essentially to allow me to store the selection in the users session as they select users and move to different pages.

The form works correctly on the first page, however when you move to the second page, only the first selection works.  Any selection made after that throws the error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormAjaxResponseBuilder->buildResponse() (line 67 of /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormAjaxResponseBuilder.php).

Here is the buildForm contents:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session $session */
    $session = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
    /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
    $node = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('node');
    if (!$session->has($node->id().'_register_selection')) {
      $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession()->set($node->id().'_register_selection', []);
    } else {
      $selected = $session->get($node->id().'_register_selection');
    }

    $form['selected_users'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'selected-users'],
    ];

    $users = $form_state->getValue('user_list');
    if (!empty($users)) {
      foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user['check'] == TRUE) {
          $selected[$user['uid']] = $user['uid'];
        } elseif (array_key_exists($user['uid'], $users)) {
            unset($selected[$user['uid']]);
        }
        $session->set($node->id() . '_register_selection', $selected);
      }
    }

    if (!empty($selected)) {
      foreach ($selected as $item) {
        $form['selected_users'][$item]['user'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => t('user: @user', ['@user' => $item]),
          '#weight' => '0',
        ];
      }
    }

    $header = [
      ['data' => $form['user_list']['check_all'] = [
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#title' => t('Select all'),
          '#return_value' => TRUE,
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' =>['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ],
        'class'=> ['py-4']
      ],
      'uid' => ['data' => t('UID'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
      'username' => ['data' => t('Username'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
      'sits_id' => ['data' => t('SITS ID'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
      'name' => ['data' => t('Name'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
      'mail' => ['data' => t('Email'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
      'college' => ['data' => t('College'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
      'programme' => ['data' => t('Programme'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
      'course' => ['data' => t('Course'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
      'year' => ['data' => t('Year'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    ];

    $form['user_list'] = [
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#empty' => t('No users found with the selected filters.'),
      '#prefix' => "<div class='table-responsive mt-3'>",
      '#suffix' => "</div>",
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['table-sm'],
        'style' => 'font-size: .85rem',
      ]
    ];

    $query = $this->database->select('users_field_data', 'ufd');
    $query->leftJoin('profile', 'profile', 'profile.uid = ufd.uid');
    $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_sits_id', 'sitsid', 'sitsid.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
    $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_first_name', 'fname', 'fname.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
    $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_last_name', 'lname', 'lname.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
    $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_college', 'college', 'college.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
    $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_programme', 'programme', 'programme.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
    $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_course', 'course', 'course.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
    $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_sits_year', 'year', 'year.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
    $query->fields('ufd', ['uid','name', 'mail']);
    $query->addField('sitsid', 'field_prof_sits_id_value', 'sits_id');
    $query->addField('fname', 'field_prof_first_name_value', 'first_name');
    $query->addField('lname', 'field_prof_last_name_value', 'last_name');
    $query->addField('college', 'field_prof_college_target_id', 'college_gid');
    $query->addField('programme', 'field_prof_programme_target_id', 'programme_gid');
    $query->addField('course', 'field_prof_course_target_id', 'course_gid');
    $query->addField('year', 'field_prof_sits_year_value', 'year');
    $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')->orderByHeader($header);
    $pager = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(10);

    $results = $pager->execute()->fetchAll();
    if ($results) {
      foreach ($results as $data) {
        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['check'] = [
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::processUser',
            'wrapper' => 'selected-users',
          ],
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0', 'p-0', 'text-align-center']
          ],
          '#attributes' => [
            'class' => ['m-0'],
            'style' => 'position:relative;',
          ],
          '#default_value' => isset($selected[$data->uid]) ? TRUE : FALSE,
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['uid'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->uid,
          '#value' => $data->uid,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['username'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->name,
          '#value' => $data->name,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['sits_id'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->sits_id,
          '#value' => $data->sits_id,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['name'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->first_name . ' ' . $data->last_name,
          '#value' => $data->first_name . ' ' . $data->last_name,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['mail'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->mail,
          '#value' => $data->mail,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['college'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->college_gid,
          '#value' => $data->college_gid,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['programme'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->programme_gid,
          '#value' => $data->programme_gid,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['course'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->course_gid,
          '#value' => $data->course_gid,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];

        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['year'] = [
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#markup' => $data->year,
          '#value' => $data->year,
          '#weight' => '0',
          '#wrapper_attributes' => [
            'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
          ]
        ];
      }
    }

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['mb-4', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-center']
      ]
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Register'),
      '#name' => 'update',
    ];

    $form['pager'] = ['#type' => 'pager'];

    return $form;
  }
}
```

And the processUser callback:

```
  public function processUser(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['selected_users'];
  }
```

This seems to work correctly without pagination. Enabling pagination makes it break. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! _Has anyone experienced this before?_ is not actually asking a question, but polling. We need a more specific question, for example _What do I need to change in this code to avoid it throws an exception?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found that if you use a different approach to pagination the ajax issue is no longer present.

I removed the pagination extender in the database query and have initialised the pager manually.

This code now works:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  /** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session $session */
  $session = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();
  /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
  $node = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('node');
  if (!$session->has($node->id().'_register_selection')) {
    $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSession()->set($node->id().'_register_selection', []);
  } else {
    $selected = $session->get($node->id().'_register_selection');
  }

  $form['selected_users'] = [
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => ['id' => 'selected-users'],
  ];

  $users = $form_state->getValue('user_list');
  if (!empty($users)) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
      if ($user['check'] == TRUE) {
        $selected[$user['uid']] = $user['uid'];
      } elseif (array_key_exists($user['uid'], $users)) {
        unset($selected[$user['uid']]);
      }
      $session->set($node->id() . '_register_selection', $selected);
    }
  }

  if (!empty($selected)) {
    foreach ($selected as $item) {
      $form['selected_users'][$item]['user'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => t('user: @user', ['@user' => $item]),
        '#weight' => '0',
      ];
    }
  }

  $header = [
    ['data' => $form['user_list']['check_all'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Select all'),
      '#return_value' => TRUE,
      '#wrapper_attributes' => [
        'class' =>['align-middle', 'm-0']
      ]
    ],
      'class'=> ['py-4']
    ],
    'uid' => ['data' => t('UID'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    'username' => ['data' => t('Username'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    'sits_id' => ['data' => t('SITS ID'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    'name' => ['data' => t('Name'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    'mail' => ['data' => t('Email'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    'college' => ['data' => t('College'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    'programme' => ['data' => t('Programme'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    'course' => ['data' => t('Course'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
    'year' => ['data' => t('Year'), 'class'=> ['align-middle', 'py-4']],
  ];

  $form['user_list'] = [
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#empty' => t('No users found with the selected filters.'),
    '#prefix' => "<div class='table-responsive mt-3'>",
    '#suffix' => "</div>",
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['table-sm'],
      'style' => 'font-size: .85rem',
    ]
  ];

  $query = $this->database->select('users_field_data', 'ufd');
  $query->leftJoin('profile', 'profile', 'profile.uid = ufd.uid');
  $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_sits_id', 'sitsid', 'sitsid.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
  $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_first_name', 'fname', 'fname.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
  $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_last_name', 'lname', 'lname.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
  $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_college', 'college', 'college.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
  $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_programme', 'programme', 'programme.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
  $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_course', 'course', 'course.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
  $query->leftJoin('profile__field_prof_sits_year', 'year', 'year.entity_id = profile.profile_id');
  $query->fields('ufd', ['uid','name', 'mail']);
  $query->addField('sitsid', 'field_prof_sits_id_value', 'sits_id');
  $query->addField('fname', 'field_prof_first_name_value', 'first_name');
  $query->addField('lname', 'field_prof_last_name_value', 'last_name');
  $query->addField('college', 'field_prof_college_target_id', 'college_gid');
  $query->addField('programme', 'field_prof_programme_target_id', 'programme_gid');
  $query->addField('course', 'field_prof_course_target_id', 'course_gid');
  $query->addField('year', 'field_prof_sits_year_value', 'year');
  $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')->orderByHeader($header);
  $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

  if ($results) {
    $page = pager_find_page();
    $num_per_page = 5;
    $offset = $num_per_page * $page;
    pager_default_initialize(count($results), $num_per_page);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($results as $data) {
      if ($i++ < $offset) continue;
      if ($i > $offset + $num_per_page) break;

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['check'] = [
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::processUser',
          'wrapper' => 'selected-users',
        ],
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0', 'p-0', 'text-align-center']
        ],
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['m-0'],
          'style' => 'position:relative;',
        ],
        '#default_value' => isset($selected[$data->uid]) ? TRUE : FALSE,
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['uid'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->uid,
        '#value' => $data->uid,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['username'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->name,
        '#value' => $data->name,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['sits_id'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->sits_id,
        '#value' => $data->sits_id,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->first_name . ' ' . $data->last_name,
        '#value' => $data->first_name . ' ' . $data->last_name,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['mail'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->mail,
        '#value' => $data->mail,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['college'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->college_gid,
        '#value' => $data->college_gid,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['programme'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->programme_gid,
        '#value' => $data->programme_gid,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['course'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->course_gid,
        '#value' => $data->course_gid,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];

      $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['year'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $data->year,
        '#value' => $data->year,
        '#weight' => '0',
        '#wrapper_attributes' => [
          'class' => ['align-middle', 'm-0']
        ]
      ];
    }
  }

  $form['actions'] = [
    '#type' => 'actions',
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['mb-4', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-center']
    ]
  ];

  $form['actions']['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Register'),
    '#name' => 'update',
  ];

  $form[] = ['#type' => 'pager'];

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding ajaxified form elements in a loop I always use unique array keys on the lowest level:

```
      foreach ($results as $data) {
        $form['user_list'][$data->uid]['check' . $data->uid] = [
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::processUser',
            'wrapper' => 'selected-users',
          ],
          ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will keep that in mind.  Unfortunately that did not solve the problem as the error still persists after changing the array key.